# Order students by highest grade and then order grades for each student

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

| Student | Grade | Course |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JOHN | 10 | Algebra |
| JOHN | 7 | Computer science |
| ANNA | 10 | Algebra |
| ANNA | 10 | Data structures |
| JACOB | 10 | Data structures |
| GEORGE | 6 | Computer science |
| GEORGE | 10 | Algebra |
| GEORGE | 9 | Data structures |

I have the above table and what I want to do is to order the students by their highest course grade (a student with 10 & 10 comes first compared to someone with a 10 or 10 & 9 or even someone with 10 & 9 & 9) and then order the courses by grade for each student. The result should look like the table below:

| Student | Grade | Course |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ANNA | 10 | Data structures |
| ANNA | 10 | Computer science |
| GEORGE | 10 | Algebra |
| GEORGE | 9 | Data structures |
| GEORGE | 6 | Algebra |
| JOHN | 10 | Algebra |
| JOHN | 7 | Computer science |
| JACOB | 10 | Data structures |

Is there a way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this query:

```
SELECT Student, GROUP_CONCAT(LPAD(Grade, 2, '0') ORDER BY Grade DESC) grades
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Student
```

you get for each student all grades left padded with `0` in a comma separated list:

| Student | grades |
| --- | --- |
| ANNA | 10,10 |
| GEORGE | 10,09,06 |
| JACOB | 10 |
| JOHN | 10,07 |

You can join the above query to the table and sort by that list of grades descending:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tablename t 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Student, GROUP_CONCAT(LPAD(Grade, 2, '0') ORDER BY Grade DESC) grades
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY Student
) g ON g.Student = t.Student
ORDER BY grades DESC, Grade DESC
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=91246e973ed2d3f50c9d53150d0bdc18).
Results:

| Student | Grade | Course |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ANNA | 10 | Algebra |
| ANNA | 10 | Data structures |
| GEORGE | 10 | Algebra |
| GEORGE | 9 | Data structures |
| GEORGE | 6 | Computer science |
| JOHN | 10 | Algebra |
| JOHN | 7 | Computer science |
| JACOB | 10 | Data structures |

Comment: @firoas Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You can use window functions in the `ORDER BY` clause.  So:

```
order by max(grade) over (partition by student) desc,
         student,
         grade desc
```

Comment: This is really close but it only takes into consideration the max value. If a student has 10 & 10 in 2 courses, and another one has 10, or 9, the second one might show up first. What I want to do is to compare the number of 10s between 2 students. If they both have the same number of 10s, they should be compared by the immediate next max value, in the same way.

Comment: @Babis.amas . . . That is very tricky to do in MySQL.  You might stick with the maximum and then the average.

Comment: I thought so but I was hoping there might be a solution. Thank you vey much for your time.